# How do i clear a "setTimeout" proprely JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cleartimeout

i have this simple page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>Click the second button to skip the timeout!</p> 


    <button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop the alert</button>

<script>
var myVar;

spamHi();

function spamHi() {
 console.log("Hi!");
 setTimeout(spamHi,3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearTimeout(spamHi);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The function spamHi() prints "Hi!" in the console every 3 seconds.
What the function myStopFunction() is supposed to do is 
to clear the delay to enable the console to print "Hi!" immediately without waiting the 3 seconds.

How can i fix this?

Comment: You might want to look into [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead of constantly resetting your timeout. The provided answer is correct through in either case, you need to store the ID of the timeout or interval and `clearTimeout` or `clearInterval` to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the return of the setTimeout call and then pass it to the clearTimeout function:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(spamHi, 3000);

clearTimeout(timeout);
```